# Format phone number entries using googlelibphonenumer and angular pipes as and when you type

Tags: angular, typescript

Expected end result : format number entries in 999-999-9999 format as and when you type, and restrict entry for more than 10 digits

I am able to achieve this using reqular experessions

could some one help me achieve the same using google-libphonenumber and angular pipes

//html
input  type="tel" id="phoneNum" [(ngModel)]="phoneNo" (keyup)="onInputChange()"

---

```
export class PhoneComponent implements OnInit{
    phoneNo : string = "9876543210";

    onInputChange() {
        let newVal = this.phoneNo.replace(/\D/g, '');
        if (newVal.length === 0) {
            newVal = '';
        } else if (newVal.length <= 3) {
            newVal = newVal.replace(/^(\d{0,3})/, '$1');
        } else if (newVal.length <= 6) {
            newVal = newVal.replace(/^(\d{0,3})(\d{0,3})/, '$1-$2');
        } else if (newVal.length <= 10) {
            newVal = newVal.replace(/^(\d{0,3})(\d{0,3})(\d{0,4})/, '$1-$2-$3');
        } else {
            newVal = newVal.substring(0, 10);
            newVal = newVal.replace(/^(\d{0,3})(\d{0,3})(\d{0,4})/, '$1-$2-$3');
        }
        this.phoneNo = newVal;
        console.log('input : ' + newVal);
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

npm i google-libphonenumber@latest --save

npm i @types/google-libphonenumber@latest --save-dev

make sure in tsconfig inside compiler options you have this :-

```
"typeRoots": [
            "node_modules/@types"
        ]
```

Pipe Code :-

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { PhoneNumberUtil, PhoneNumberFormat } from 'google-libphonenumber';
@Pipe({
  name: 'phoneformat'
})
export class PhonePipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
    //return (formatting code from googlephonelib)
  }
}
```

Example template :-

```
<hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="phone">
<div>{{phone | phoneformat}}</div>
```